# Ranking over multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, partitioning, ranking

I have this data frame:

```
dict_data = {'id' : [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
'datetime' : np.array(['2016-01-03T16:05:52.000000000', '2016-01-03T16:05:52.000000000',
       '2016-01-03T16:05:52.000000000', '2016-01-27T15:45:20.000000000',
       '2016-01-27T15:45:20.000000000', '2016-11-27T15:08:04.000000000',
       '2016-11-27T15:08:04.000000000', '2016-11-27T15:08:04.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')}

df_data=pd.DataFrame(dict_data)
```

The data looks like this

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN3LC.png)

I want to rank over customer id and date, I used this code

```
    (df_data.assign(rn=df_data.sort_values(['datetime'], ascending=True)
....:                     .groupby(['datetime','id'])
....:                     .cumcount() + 1)
....:      .sort_values(['datetime','rn'])
....: )
```

I get a different rank by ID for each date:

[table with rank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD8A5.png)

What I would like to see is rank by ID but for the same datetime get the same rank for each ID.

Comment: Maybe provide an actual layout of your desired output? :) not sure I fully get it!

Comment: And adding import pandas as pd, import numpy as np would help as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can rank by datetime and id :

```
##### RANK BY datetime and id #####
In[]: df_data.rank(axis =0,ascending = 1, method = 'dense')
Out[]: 
   datetime  id
0         1   1
1         1   1
2         1   1
3         2   2
4         2   2
5         3   2
6         3   2
7         3   2

##### GROUPBY id AND USE APPLY TO GET VALUE FOR FOR EACH GROUP #####
In[]: df_data.rank(axis =0,ascending = 1, method = 'dense').groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x)
Out[]: 
   datetime  id
0         1   1
1         1   1
2         1   1
3         2   2
4         2   2
5         3   2
6         3   2
7         3   2

##### THEN RANK INSIDE EACH GROUP #####

In[]: df_data.assign(rank=df_data.rank(axis =0,ascending = 1, method = 'dense').groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.rank(axis =0,ascending = 1, method = 'dense'))['datetime'])
Out[]: 
             datetime  id  rank
0 2016-01-03 16:05:52   1     1
1 2016-01-03 16:05:52   1     1
2 2016-01-03 16:05:52   1     1
3 2016-01-27 15:45:20   2     1
4 2016-01-27 15:45:20   2     1
5 2016-11-27 15:08:04   2     2
6 2016-11-27 15:08:04   2     2
7 2016-11-27 15:08:04   2     2
```

If you want to change the method of ranking you'll get more info on ranking from the [pandas documentation on ranking](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html)

Comment: Abhijay I want to partition by ID as well. So for ID=2 rank will start from 1 a well.

Comment: @Nick it's not clearly mentioned in the question. Please edit. I hope this is the desired result that you wanted.

Comment: @ Abhijay Ghildyal the dense rank does not seem to work as intended. For example for ID=2 all datetimes =2016-01-27 15:45:20 should have rank 1 and all datetimes=2016-11-27 15:08:04  should have rank=2

Comment: @Nick I made the changes accordingly. Please add sample output with your question to make it cogent.